# How to remove only html tags in a string?

Tags: php, regex

I have written code for removing HTML tags, but it is also removing `a<b` type of strings. I want it to not to remove strings like `2<3` or `a<b`.

```
$term="a<b";
echo "Text is--->".preg_replace('/(?:<|&lt;).+?(?:>|&gt;)/', '', $term);
```

How do I remove html tags in a string, without removing LT or GT?

Comment: Why don't you use `strip_tags`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Use proper entities: `$term = "a&lt;b";`, angle-brackets should *not* be output to HTML *unless* they're part of a tag's opening, or closing. Given the regex this won't prevent your problem, but why are you removing both `<` and `&lt;` and *then* having a problem with the regex not allowing `a<b` to pass unaffected?

Comment: BTW: if you do proper output encoding you might not need to remove the tags (unless this is really HTML and you want to,get the plaintext from it (in that case however "a<b" would not be valid HTML

Answer (score 10):

Sorry I had not validate enough.

I have checked php5-cli expression below.

```
(?:<|&lt;)\/?([a-zA-Z]+) *[^<\/]*?(?:>|&gt;)
```

PHP code goes:

```
#!/usr/bin/php 
<?php

$str = "<html></html>
a<b 1<2 3>1 
<body>1>2</body>
<style file=\"'googe'\" alt=\"google\">hello world</style>
<have a good efghijknopqweryuip[]asdfgghjkzxcv bnm,.me>hello world<> google com</s>
<a se=\"font: googe;\">abcde</a>";

echo "text--->".preg_replace('/(?:<|&lt;)\/?([a-zA-Z]+) *[^<\/]*?(?:>|&gt;)/', '', $str)."\n";

?>
```

Result:

```
text--->
a<b 1<2 3>1 
1>2
hello world
hello world<> google com
abcde
```

Comment: Using this regular expression, "<b<b>>" would become "<b>". If you want to stop users adding their own HTML, don't use this as they can get around it.

Answer (score 8):

Use strip tags function of php

```
echo strip_tags($html)
```

Comment: i have used strip_tags(), but this will remove "<b" from "a<b".

Answer (score 1):

Strip_tags function is good solution.

But if you need regex, use expression below.

`(?:<|&lt;)\/?([a-z]+) *[^\/(?:<|&lt;)]*?(?:>|&gt;)`

Comment: Hi Hoon, thanks for the reply. strip_tags() are removing "<b" from "a<b". above regex is giving error.

Answer (score 1):

## Remove all HTML tags from PHP string with content!

Let say you have string contains anchor tag and you want to remove this tag with content then this method will helpful.

```
$srting = '<a title="" href="/index.html"><b>Some Text</b></a> a<b';

echo strip_tags_content($srting);

function strip_tags_content($text) {

    return preg_replace('@<(\w+)\b.*?>.*?</\1>@si', '', $text);
    
 }
```

Output:

> a < b

Retrieved from: [Remove all html tags from php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string/39320168#39320168)

Answer (score -1):

Use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
//If you want to allow some tags
$term = strip_tags($term,"<b>");
```

Comment: This will strip any value not listed. So if you want to allow any math form e.g. `x<y` you'd have to list every single combination in the allowable tags area.