# laravel - How to limit text string not including html tags

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a field in database which contains html tags. I want to show that field in the view without showing HTML tags. I used `str_limit($value, $limit = 100, $end = '...')` but it shows the html tags also. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `strip_tags()` function.

For example this filters the `<b></b>` tags:

```
<?php
echo strip_tags("Hello <b>world!</b>");
?>
```

In your case would be something along the lines of:

```
<?php
   strip_tags($value);
?>
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/strip_tags).

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string).

Answer (score 0):

str_limit only limits the number of characters. What you need to do is parse the database string and remove anything that looks like a tag. I've never used it, but the php strip_tags function might be more what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know any sample that shows that?

Comment: I might also add that if you're stripping tags for security measures (which is extremely important!), this method is not sufficient. htmlspecialchars() is much more effective for this, but alone is still prone to problems.