# php regex to match algebraic equation within a dynamic string

Tags: php, regex

I have strings as following

```
3<em>a +</em> 2<em>b</em>

2<em>a </em> - 2<em>b</em>
```

and I want to convert them to following

3*a +* 2*b*

2*a*  - 2*b*

Strings may or may not have `<em></em>` tags

Basically I need to parse algebraic equations from a dynamic string.

Following are some cases that code should consider:

```
2<em>a </em>- (<em>a </em>- 2<em>b)</em>
<em>a&nbsp;</em>- 2<em>b</em>
<em>a </em>+&nbsp;2<em>b</em>
3<em>a +</em>&nbsp;2<em>b</em>
(<em>p</em>&nbsp;+ 2)
(<em>p</em>&nbsp;- 3)
<em>not an algebraic equation. tags should not be truncated.</em>
```

I tried to match the above strings using a regex, but could'nt.

PHP code:

```
$string = "3<em>a +</em> 2<em>b</em>";
$pattern = '#(\d{0,9}<em>a.*</em>)#';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
echo json_encode($matches);
```

In the pattern I am trying to match an `a` inside `<em></em>` preceded by a digit.

EDIT: I cannot use `strip_tags` or related logic to truncate out the `<em></em>` because my content is dynamic and I want this change only where the match is an ***algebraic equation***.

Comment: [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all html tags from php string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string)

Comment: Could you be more precise as to *why* you cannot use `strip_tags()` ? When you can apply a regex in `PHP` you can very well apply other functions as well. Or is the output coming via JavaScript? Otherwise a regex like `(</?[^>]+>)` strips every HTML tag, see https://regex101.com/r/oC1rK4/1

Comment: See if [this demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/514842) helps. Depending on how source where your parse out looks like. Please add source and if you want to extract those equations or replace them.

Comment: @bobblebubble it works for all cases except the last one. strings other than algebraic equation should not be altered.

Comment: You can try to filter those out [like in this demo](https://eval.in/515541).

Comment: instead of comment, add this as an answer please.

Comment: @bobblebubble opening tag should not be stripped out. `not an algebraic equation. tags should not be truncated.<\/em>`

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to replace those in a html document without <em>... or do you want to extract those equations? If you want to replace, please give a sample of the full input at eg [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: looks like it works. will check with other cases and get back. please add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strip_tags` for removing **HTML** tags:

```
$string = "3<em>a +</em> 2<em>b</em>";
echo strip_tags($string);

// second string
$string2 = "2<em>a </em> - 2<em>b</em>";
echo strip_tags($string2);
```

**Result:**

```
3a + 2b
2a - 2b
```

---

**UPDATE:**

remove tags if pattern match:

```
<?php
$string = "2<em>a </em> - 2<em>b</em>";
$pattern = '#(\d{0,9}<em>a.*</em>)#';
if(preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)){
    echo strip_tags($matches[0]);
}
?>
```

Comment: I cant use strip_tags, please check the updated question.

Comment: well it means, when pattern match, remove the tags right? @hiteshisrani

Comment: yes. we are in the right direction. However matching the pattern is important. In your regex `2<em>b</em> - 2<em>a </em>` will fail.

Comment: @hiteshisrani: it means, we need to remove spaces aswell

Comment: remove spaces between a digit and a variable. not otherwise. e.g `2 a` should be `2a` but `2a + 3b` should remain as it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//Step 1. Get Html
$html = "3<em style='color:#000;'>a +</em> 2<em>b</em>";

//Step 2. Get pattern (to match html tags)
$patt = '/<[^>]+>/';

//Step 3. Remove all tags
$html = str_replace($patt, '', $html);

//Step 4. Remove all spaces
$html = str_replace(' ', '', $html);

echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: I cant use strip_tags, please check the updated question.

Comment: `<?php
 $html = '3<em>a+</em>2<em>b</em>';
$html = str_replace('\<[a-zA-Z _-/]{1,}>\ ', '', $html);
echo $html;
?>`

Comment: This is more close. However the pattern needs to be corrected/improved for it will fail for some cases. I will update such cases. Please update your answer with the regex based solution.

Comment: also I want to truncate `<em></em>` wherever there is a match

Comment: firstly It will truncate tags other than `<em></em>` also check the last case from the original question.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <?php
$string = "2<em>an&nbsp;</em> - 2<em>a</em>";
$pattern = '#(\d{0,9}<em>[a-zA-Z].*</em>)#';
if(preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)){
    $a=strip_tags($matches[0]);
    echo str_replace('&nbsp;','',$a);
}
?>
```

Comment: yes that's an improved version of @devpro's answer. But I am worried it will fail for some cases. I will update soon.

Comment: Yes of course we can truncate `&nbsps;`  Pattern wont work for equations under braces. see the last two cases.

Comment: since it dont has <em>

Comment: you only said to match with <em> and remove it. you should say that string may contain <em> .

Comment: updated the question. though I am looking for an updated, improved version. +1 for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
<?php $string = "3<em>a +</em> 2<em>b</em>";
$pattern = '/^\d<em>\w\s\S<\/em>\s\d<em>\w<\/em>$/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: This won't erase the second html tag (bound to the beginning).

Comment: it wont work for other cases. consider `3<em>b +</em> 2<em>a</em>` Just shifted the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach, see [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/xIFLxB):

```
<?php
$string = "2<em>a </em>- (<em>a </em>- 2<em>b)</em>
<em>a&nbsp;</em>- 2<em>b</em>
<em>a </em>+&nbsp;2<em>b</em>
3<em>a +</em>&nbsp;2<em>b</em>
(<em>p</em>&nbsp;+ 2)
(<em>p</em>&nbsp;- 3)";

$regex = '~(</?[^>]+>|&nbsp;)~';
# looks for html tags (open and closing tags) or &nbsp; literally

$string = preg_replace($regex, "", $string);
echo $string;
// output:
// 2a - (a - 2b)
// a- 2b
// a +2b
// 3a +2b
// (p+ 2)
// (p- 3)
?>
```

### Demos:

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lK2dI9/1) and [ideone](http://ideone.com/xIFLxB).
Still, why is `strip_tags()` not an option?

Comment: there are some tags that I dont want to truncate. like I want to keep <img> <table>

Comment: @hiteshisrani: Then see this updated demo on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/lK2dI9/2 Simply enumerate tags you want to keep.

Comment: brilliant! this was helpul

Comment: @hiteshisrani: Consider accepting it as an answer then :-)

Comment: Yes you got it almost correct. one problem though. please check https://regex101.com/r/lK2dI9/3 only equations to be considered

Comment: @hiteshisrani: This is getting very complicated now - how to distinguish between an equation and text? There could as well be parentheses or digits in your paragraph. Better check if you could **only** input equations beforehand (maybe depending on the string length or sth.?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102972/discussion-between-hitesh-israni-and-jan).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, you want to extract those equations. For me it's unclear what is your actual goal.

1.) Use something like `[\d)(]*(?:</?em>[^><\r\n]*)+` to extract lines that contain `<em`...
[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yO2sR3/1). This is only for getting the lines.

2.) Remove the tags and `&nbsp;` and check if the lines look like an equation by eg checking if there's at least what could be an arithmetic operator `[*/+-]` and a digit `\d` in it.

```
if(preg_match_all('~[\d)(]*(?:</?em>[^><\r\n]*)+~', $str, $out))
{
  foreach($out[0] AS $v)
  {
    $v = preg_replace(['~</?em>~', '~&nbsp;~'], ["", " "], $v);
    if (preg_match('~[*/+-]~', $v) && preg_match('~\d~i', $v))
      $eq[] = $v;
  }
}
```

You could of course improve the check to identifiy equations better.
[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/515541)

Answer (score 0):

Why not search and replace all instances of `<em>` and `</em>`?

```
$string = "3<em>a +</em> 2<em>b</em>";

$string = str_replace("<em>", "", $string);
$string = str_replace("</em>", "", $string);

echo $string; //3a + 2b
```

Comment: My content is dynamic. and its not necessary that only algebraic-equation will come inside `<em></em>`. However I only want to match algebraic-equations

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function `strip_tags` to remove HTML tags form string. You can use it.

```
$string = "3<em>a +</em> 2<em>b</em>";
echo strip_tags($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '3<em>a +</em> 2<em>b</em>';
$pattern = '#\d{1}<em>\w{1} \+</em> \d{1}<em>\w{1}</em>#'; 

preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: did you check the output of your pattern? `["3a +<\/em> 2b<\/em>"]`

Comment: also you are being too specific, what if the equation is `3a + 9` or `a + 2b`