# Filter data from email trail in php

Tags: php, ldap

I have a table that contains data from a forum. In that forum user can post question/answer from email as well. So some email data having email trail is being stored in the table. Now when we are fetching data of questions/answers, then due to bad structured data, we are facing problem in html.

```
    ---18013450-1896087034-1412716023=:54627
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

The maximum number of units for patch testing is 40 units for lorem.=0A=
=0A=0A                                lorem lorem =0A=0A=0AOn Tuesday, Oc=
tober 7, 2014 3:06 PM, lorem <lorem@lorem.net> wrote:=0A  =0A=0A=0AD=
oes anyone know the new amount of patch tests that is allowed by lorem? =
We used to be able to bill for over 80 but now claims are being denied. I h=
ave heard there is a maximum they will pay for now but they will not tell y=
ou what that number is when you call.=0A___________________________________=
________________=0A=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BDInformation About This Message =EF=BF=
=BD=EF=BF=BD=0AYou are currently subscribed to lorem =0A  as lorem=
00@lorem.com=0A=EF=BF=BD You can send mail to this list at: =0A  lorem@co=
lorem.lorem =0A=EF=BF=BD To view the archives, or change options, visit =0Ah=
lorem To =
unsubscribe send a BLANK email to =0Aleave-25204941-545882U@lorem.net fr=
om YOUR e-mail account.=0A_________________________________________________=
__=0ACustomer Service: lorem=0ACopyright 2011, 
=0AThis message was originated by member: lorem.lorem
---18013450-1896087034-1412716023=:54627
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body><div style=3D"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:He=
lveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;fo=
nt-size:14px"><div><span>The maximum number of units for patch testing is 4=
0 units for lorem.</span></div><div style=3D"color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-f=
amily: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans=
-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; background-color: transparent;=
"><span><br></span></div><div style=3D"color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: He=
lveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; f=
ont-size: 14px; font-style: normal; background-color: transparent;"><span><=
br></span></div><div style=3D"color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: HelveticaNe=
ue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; font-size:=
 14px; font-style: normal; background-color:
 transparent;"><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;=
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nb=
sp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; lorem lorem</sp=
an></div> <div class=3D"qtdSeparateBR"><br><br></div><div class=3D"yahoo_qu=
oted" style=3D"display: block;"> <div style=3D"font-family: HelveticaNeue, =
Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; font-size: 14p=
x;"> <div style=3D"font-family: HelveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, A=
rial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;"> <div dir=3D"ltr"> <font=
 face=3D"Arial" size=3D"2"> On Tuesday, October 7, 2014 3:06 PM, lorem &l=
t;lorem@lorem.net&gt; wrote:<br> </font> </div>  <br><br> <div class=
=3D"y_msg_container">Does anyone know the new amount of patch tests that is=
 allowed by Medicare? We used to be able to bill for over 80 but now claims=
 are being denied. I have heard there is a maximum they will pay for now bu=
t they will
 not tell you what that number is when you call.<br>_______________________=
____________________________<br>=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BDInformation About This Me=
ssage =EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD<br>You are currently subscribed to lorem <br>&nb=
sp; as <a href=3D"mailto:loremlorem00@yahoo.com" ymailto=3D"mailto:loremr=
edding00@yahoo.com">loremlorem00@yahoo.com</a><br>=EF=BF=BD You can send =
mail to this list at: <br>&nbsp; <a href=3D"mailto:lorem@lorem.net" ym=
ailto=3D"mailto:lorem@lorem.net">lorem@lorem.net</a> <br>=EF=BF=
=BD To view the archives, or change options, visit <br><br>=EF=BF=BD T=
o unsubscribe send a BLANK email to <br><a href=3D"mailto:leave-25204941-54=
5882U@lorem.net" ymailto=3D"mailto:leave-25204941-545882U@lorem.net">=
leave-25204941-545882U@lorem.net</a> from YOUR e-mail
 account.<br>___________________________________________________<br>lorem=
der Customer Service: lorem<br>Copyright 2011, lorem =
lorem<br>This message was originated by member: author.nameemail<br><br><br><=
/div>  </div> </div>  </div> </div></body></html>
---18013450-1896087034-1412716023=:54627--
```

We are using nl2br to convert new lines. But the div and css tags inside the content is breaking the output.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Jawed

Comment: Guess you shouldn't write that markup into your table in the first place. Check PHP's filters or google for something like "php filter html".

Comment: I have the data migrated from another system. We are building new system that should show old data. So we can't do anything for existing data. Just have to parse it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string