# substr(htmlcode) without breaking html <tags>

Tags: php, jquery

How do I truncate an HTML string without breaking the HTML code?
I am using following code but it is not working.

```
<?php
$title ="<div class='links'>I've tried the <b>other examples</b> above and they did not produce the desired results.
<ul>
<b>
<li>lorem ispum</li>
<li>lorem ispum</li>
<li>lorem ispum</li>
</b>
</ul>
<h1>Heading1</h1>
<div class='links'>
<h2>heading2</h2>
<span>loremispum dollar sit amet.</span>
</div>
</div>";
$text = substr( $title, 0, strpos($title, ' ', 105) );
echo $text;
?>
<div>Some Text Goes here</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am wondering if you need to retain the HTML formatting, or if you should strip the HTML tags first and then do a substring..
[Remove all html tags from php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string)

Comment: I don't want to strip html tags.I have to keep the html structure.