# remove html code after a certain character php

Tags: php, html, regex, substr

Question: I have full html code inserted into mysql database. I want to remove everything after `Product Description`. How would I do it?

```
<p>hjfsdgfsgdfjsdgfjgdsjfgsdjgfjsdgf </p>
<p>Product Description</p>
```

I want to store into the database again with the html format.

Comment: <p>hjfsdgfsgdfjsdgfjgdsjfgsdjgfjsdgf</p>

<div class="ui-box product-description-main" id="j-product-description">
 <div class="ui-box-title">Product Description</div>
 <div class="ui-box-body">

Comment: I just want <p>hjfsdgfsgdfjsdgfjgdsjfgsdjgfjsdgf</p>. Rest everything should be removed. <p>hjfsdgfsgdfjsdgfjgdsjfgsdjgfjsdgf</p> is just the example. Instead of those text, I have another bunch of html code.

Comment: Starting from:   

<div class="ui-box product-description-main" id="j-product-description">

everything should be removed. I have tried this:

$description = preg_replace("/<div class='ui-box product-description-main' id='j-product-description'>.*$/", '', $descrow[1]);

But no luck with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all html tags from php string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string)

Comment: Why did you try `<div class='ui-box product-description-main' id='j-product-description'>.*`? There's no `div` in your code.. or is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to the question proposed in the comments of your original question, you can do something like this:

```
preg_replace("/<div class=\"ui-box product-description-main\".*/sm", " ",$your_html_goes_here);
```

This removes everything after the div element with classes 'ui-box' and 'product-description-main'.

By the same token, answering your original question is fairly simple:

```
preg_replace("/(<p>Product Description<\/p>).*/sm", "$1", $your_html_goes_here);
```

This removes everything after the paragraph 'Product Description'.
If you need more information about the regex proposed in my answer,let me know.

Comment: let me check. wil let you know within few minutes

Comment: it worked perfectly fine. Thanks @G. Margaritis

Comment: I have some question related to regex. how would I contact you?

Comment: @Vky Of course.Tell me your question

Comment: @Vky contact me in my email: margaeor@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

Comment: something like this but everything should be truncated after <div class="ui-box product-description-main" id="j-product-description">

Comment: http://www.addiszone.com/test.png

have a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:

```
$lookup = "Product Description";
$fullText = "..."; //full html code goes here
$pos = strpos($fullText, $lookup);

echo substr($fullText, 0, $pos);
```

This will print your string contents until "Product Description" position. If you also want to get rid of possible html tags, just use `strip_tags` as recommended in other answers

Comment: how to combine both answers? I dont have any clue about strip_tags

Comment: remove html tags and text and again store them into the database with the same format.

Comment: @Vky just do `$fullText = strip_tags($fullText);` before  `$pos = strpos ...` line