# how to remove hyperlink from words

Tags: php, hyperlink

i have a content like this:

> In the world where everything is decided by games, [Disboard](http://no-game-no-life.wikia.com/wiki/Disboard).

i want to remove hyperlink from ***Disboard***, im using `strip_tags()` but its not working.

here is my code:

```
<?php custom_echo (html_entity_decode(strip_tags($value['konten'],'')), 660); ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all html tags from php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string)

Comment: It should work  : https://eval.in/854062

Comment: im already use `strip_tags` but not working

Comment: can you make a live demo which not works for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'In the world where everything is decided by games,<a 
href="www.google.com">Hyperlink</a>';
$str = htmlspecialchars ($str);
echo html_entity_decode(strip_tags( $str ));
```

if the string in $str has its htmlcharacters being converted (like here), strip_tags cant remove them.

try

```
echo strip_tags( html_entity_decode( $str ));
```