# Cut off text after a certain amount of characters via substr fail

Tags: php, wordpress, substr

I have a wordpress site for news, where i have to cut the text after certain amount of characters. It all works fine via `substr()`, but when there are less than *x* characters it goes crazy and generate a nonsence in the link of the next `<li>`.

This is the code:

```
echo '<li>', get_the_date( 'd.m.Y', $recent["ID"] ), '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
$post_id = $recent["ID"];
$post_content = get_post($post_id);
$content = $post_content->post_content;
echo mb_substr(do_shortcode( $content ), 0, 200 , "utf-8");
echo "...<br> <br>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: You better trancate using words not characters and you need to keep HTML tags while truncating, here's a tutorial on how you can do so : https://www.pjgalbraith.com/truncating-text-html-with-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the $content is there any HTML? If so and that gets chopped off, it will make the next 'li' be invalid HTML, perhaps... Just found this, might be of help

[Remove all html tags from php string](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14684106/2389904)

Comment: replaced 
echo mb_substr(do_shortcode( $content ), 0, 200 , "utf-8");
by
echo mb_substr(strip_tags( $content ), 0, 200 , "utf-8");

and it works, thanks :)