# Prevent User from inserting HTML in forms

Tags: symfony

What is the best solution for removing html tags `strip_tags()` from form fields?
Should I do it in entity `setFunctions()` or **Listeners** or **DataTransformer**?

I have a form, but it's saving HTML in database, I need to remove HTML, before it's saved to the database.

Right now I have this in entity:

```
setFirstName($firstName){
    $this->firstName = strip_tags($firstName);
}
```

My question is, is this a good idea to do it like this, or is there a better practice?

Comment: Please, add more info to your question. Give us an example of your code, what you want to do and what is doing now.

Comment: @Oscar I've updated my question.

Comment: are you ussing tinyMCE or something like this? What kind of HTML are you sending to the controller?
Before persist you can get firstname, remove html tags and then setFirstname again without html tags.
Can you show your controller where `if is submitted` clossure is written?

Comment: @Oscar I'm not using tinyMCE or something like that, I just want to prevent some people of to sending html tags on purpose. I can do it in controller, but what if I have for example 10 fields that I want to strip_tag(I'd have to do it 10 times)?

Comment: Your solution, set `strip_tags` in setter method, is working?  You ask for other better solution? I wish I could help you but i dont know how...

Comment: @Oscar yes, yes it works, and exactly I'm trying to find better solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all html tags from php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string)

Comment: Why not to create validation ? Like regular expression, where you allow only a-zA-Z ?