# How to remove html tags from a text with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have retrieved some data from my MySQL database table in a text area field:

```
<textarea class='sendDesc insert' name='blog_body' placeholder='".$blogReturn->GetBlogBody()."'></textarea>
```

And it shows this as result:

[image: print screen]

Now what I want to do is to remove the html tags such as `<p>` tags from this text. So only the text will show on screen .. (with the applied css settings).

So how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all html tags from php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `strip_tags()`

```
echo strip_tags("Hello <p>world!</p>");
```