# Php: Modifying a link to just show the text

Tags: php

Below i have an existing link that represents a row in a table

```
$downloadLink =  '<a href="?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '&format=xls&table=PTable&netype=' . $neType . '&auditstarttime=' . $auditStartTime . '">[Download Excel]</a>';
```

How do i simply remove the hyperlink part of it but still keep the text? Ive tried deleting the a tags but that gives me the query etc rather than the result of it (which the link provides)

Currently it outputs this for example (in clickable form).

```
2018-07-02 00:06:00
```

I want it just to show the date without link.

Comment: Could you update your question with the expected result?

Comment: It sounds like you want to turn that one into just "[Download Excel]", is that right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all html tags from php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string)

Comment: I don't think its exact duplicate. This one is within a DDP page itself. Related-ish

Comment: Can you explain how the link you posted would ever output `2018-07-02 00:06:00` instead of `[Download Excel]`?

Answer (score 0):

Have realised i was looking at incorrect line. New to php, much apologies. Thanks for looking. I just got rid of the line below (so the reassign to a link will no longer happen)

```
     $row['auditStartTime'] = "<a href='$php_webroot/TOR/pm/pm_push_audit.php?$webargs&netype=" . $row['netype'] . "&id=" . $row['auditStartTime'] . "'>" . $row['auditStartTime'] . "</a>";
```