# how to hide html elements?

Tags: php, html

halo everyone. maybe this is the simple question but believe me. i already google it but still doesnt work. i use PHP code for this.

do i can really hide the html elements?

let say that i have database that keep every html elements like this

```
<b>Good Morning!</b> Nice to meet you!
```

but when i echo it

```
echo "<b>Good Morning!</b> Nice to meet you!";
```

The results looks like this:

> **Good Morning!** Nice to meet you!

but i need the result like this

> Good Morning! Nice to meet you!

so all the elements when display is gone. just the original words..  do this can be happen?

Comment: *i need the result like this* what do you mean "results"? A browser will display the results like this. Your question is not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) (Assuming you are using JavaScript)

Comment: @MaorRefaeli the thing is `echo` isn't a Javascript command so I'm not sure that dupe is right

Comment: Suppose you use php, then ckeck out this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strip_tags.asp

Comment: Just pick a language and google it... i.e. python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python

Comment: Do you want the bold effect?

Comment: Striping HTML tag is not a new thing. You can achieve it every language. You did not mention where you want the text to be displayed so it can on client side, server side, some script or if you want to work harder do it in bash

Comment: php tag wasn't mentioned before.. its duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string

Comment: @MrTux Let me fix your link [w3 no good](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: you can easy google this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo strip_tags("<b>Good Morning!</b> Nice to meet you!");
```

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string

Comment: ooww. seems that i not thing about word "remove html tags". i thought that is "html elements" so sorry