# PHP - substr for html texts

Tags: php, html

Basically what i want is only count the words and ignore the html properties such as: `<p></p> <span></span` etc in a sentence.

And if the words is beyond the character limit, it should put an ellipsis at the end.

**Here's my current code:**

```
function limitText($length, $value)
{
    return strlen($value) > $length ? substr($value, 0, $length) . '...' : $value;
}
```

The issue with this code is, it will also count the html.

**Current behavior:**

```
echo limitText(6, '<p>Hello</p>');
// displays:  <p>Hel...


echo limitText(2, '<p>Hello</p>');
// displays:  <p...

echo limitText(4, '<p>Hello</p>');
// displays:  <p>H...

echo limitText(8, '<p>cutie</p> <p>patootie</p>');
// displays:  <p>cutie...
```

**Desired result:**

```
echo limitText(6, '<p>Hello</p>');
// displays:  <p>Hello</p>


echo limitText(2, '<p>Hello</p>');
// displays:  <p>He...</p>

echo limitText(4, '<p>Hello</p>');
// displays:  <p>Hell...</p>

echo limitText(8, '<p>cutie</p> <p>patootie</p>');
// displays:  <p>cutie</p> <p>pat...</p>
```

Comment: use `strip_tags` in limitText()

Comment: reference link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string]

Comment: Hmm.. i need the function to return html property.. It will only display Hello instead of <p>Hello</p>

Comment: I will be needing the html properties in the front-end, since i will be converting it back to html again..

Comment: yes, but it can have styles as well.. example:

<p><strong style="color: rgb(10, 10, 10);">Lyrics: </strong></p>

Comment: @M.Hemant unlikely. If this is html, then any tags might to be

Comment: is this even possible? my issue for this is when the method returns <p>Hello..

It will break the front-end, since the paragraph didn't have a closing statement "</p>"

Comment: can you make inner text dynamic? and test tags are hard core in front end

Comment: Yes, the text is dynamic, and that text can have different html properties and styles, depends on how the maker set the text design..

Comment: Do all the strings always wrap with html tags?

Comment: @shingo yes, and it always starts with <p>

Comment: I don't have time to finnish it so anyone is free to take it from here. https://3v4l.org/QbFCW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is replace the string between `>` and `</`

```
function limitText($length, $value)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('|(?<=>)[^<>]+?(?=</)|', function ($matches) use (&$length)
    {
        if($length <= 0)
            return '';

        $str = $matches[0];
        $strlen = strlen($str);
        if($strlen > $length)
            $str = substr($str, 0, $length) . '...';
        $length -= $strlen;
        return $str;
    },
    $value);
}
```

Comment: Using Regular Expressions for manipulating HTML is bad idea. Use php DomDocument instead.

Comment: Thanks for this, i'm not sure if this is the best answer. i'll just wait for a couple of days before i accept this. thanks again @shingo

Answer (score 0):

You should combine strip_tags with str_replace like :

```
    function limitText($length, $value)
    {
        //Get the real text
        $textValue = strip_tags($value);
        //get substr of real text
        $realText = strlen($textValue) > $length ? substr($textValue, 0, $length) . '...' : $textValue;
        // replace real text with the sub text
        return str_replace($textValue, $realText, $value);
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work on this: 

limitText(6, "<p>Hel</p> <p>low worldre</p>")

Comment: Based on this, you should be easily able to handle this case.

Comment: It is not a panacea, but replace the last line by `return str_replace(explode(' ', $textValue), explode(' ', $realText), $value);` - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com

Comment: @splash58, yes i'll try this one as well.. thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
function limitText($length, $value){
    return substr(strip_tags($value), 0, $length);

}
echo limitText(1, '<h1>Hello, PHP!</h1>');
```