# export csv and html tag

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv, markup

When I export my data from my db, I have a fields called description (inside will can a html tag like `<br /><img` ....);

When I export when I read this field my cvs stop to work correctly.
I do not see inside my function what's happen.
It seems when it read something like that `<br />` it creates 2 cel one for `<br` and another for  `/>` for example

I inserted an image to shop you.

Thank you.

```
  $Qproducts = $this_Db->prepare('select p.*,
                                                       pd.* 
                                                from :table_products p,
                                                      :table_products_description pd
                                                 where p.products_id = pd.products_id
                                                 and language_id = :language_id                                                 
                                                ');
        $Qproducts->bindInt('language_id', $language_id);
        $Qproducts->execute();

        while ($Qproducts->fetch()) {
--example
              $csv[] = [
                'products_id' => $Qproducts->valueInt('products_id'),
                'products_description' => $Qproducts->value('products_description'),
           ];
        }

        ob_clean();

        if ($output == 'screen') {
          header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
        } else {
          header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
          header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=products-' . $language_id . '.csv');
        }

 echo ImportExportAdmin::csvEncode($csv, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escapechar, null, "\r\n");




public static function csvEncode(array $array, string $delimiter=',', $enclosure='"', $escape='"', $charset='utf-8', string $eol="\r\n") {
  $output = '';

  // Collect columns
  $columns = [];

  foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach (array_keys($row) as $column) {
      if (!in_array($column, $columns)) $columns[] = $column;
    }
  }

  // Collect rows and order by column order
  foreach (array_keys($array) as $row) {
    $line = [];
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
      $line[$column] = isset($array[$row][$column]) ? $array[$row][$column] : '';
    }
    $array[$row] = $line;
  }

  // Prepend column header
  array_unshift($array, array_combine($columns, $columns));

  // Build output
  foreach ($array as $row) {
    foreach (array_keys($row) as $column) {
      if (strpbrk($row[$column], $delimiter . $enclosure . $escape."\r\n") !== false) {
        $row[$column] = $enclosure . str_replace($enclosure, $escape . $enclosure, $row[$column]) . $enclosure;
      }
    }

    $output .= implode($delimiter, $row) . $eol; // Don't use fputcsv as EOL and escape char can not be customized
  }

  return preg_replace('#(\r\n|\r|\n)#', $eol, $output);
}
```

Description example

```
<img alt="" src="/test/shop/sources/images/products/70_PKAh4DX3Hy_logo.png" style="width: 70px; height: 71px;" />The 30-inch Apple Cinema HD Display delivers an amazing 2560 x 1600 pixel resolution. Designed specifically for the creative professional, this display provides more space for easier access to all the tools and palettes needed to edit, format and composite your work. Combine this display with a Mac Pro, MacBook Pro, or PowerMac G5 and there's no limit to what you can achieve.<br />
<br />
Resolutions<br />
2560 x 1600 pixels (optimum resolution)<br />
2048 x 1280<br />
1920 x 1200<br />
1280 x 800<br />
1024 x 640<br />
```

[image]

Comment: [Please don't repost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431420/csv-export-form-database).

Comment: I'm curious to know where and how has HTML markup  been allowed to be inserted in the database in the first place. That is a really bad idea.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - I included an example

Comment: Note : If I make an export via phpmyadmin in csv, works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove all html tags from php string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684077/remove-all-html-tags-from-php-string)

Comment: I tend to think that what @devlincarnate posted/flagged as a possible duplicate will solve this question. If not right away, then I'm sure you could work it a bit. So, does it seem to answer/solve this Michel? I too had thought that using `strip_tags()` would work, but I also thought about you finding and removing HTML markup in the database instead, if you're up to it. I'd make a copy/backup of it first, just in case. I'm only suggesting what "I" would do.

Comment: I used strip_tags, do not work. The goal is to import the fields, to work on excel for example and re-import all. If I break the html tag, I break the product description design page.

Comment: Your question isn't clear into your description. Please be more clear. In case you have any doubt about StackOverflow guide lines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask