# Regex to remove all empty HTML tags

Tags: php, html, regex

This is my PHP functions to remove all empty HTML tags from string input:

```
/**
 * Remove the nested HTML empty tags from the string.
 *
 * @param $string String to remove tags
 * @param null $replaceTo Replace empty string with
 * @return mixed Cleaned string
 */
function crl_remove_empty_tags($string, $replaceTo = null)
{
    // Return if string not given or empty
    if (!is_string($string) || trim($string) == '') return $string;

    // Recursive empty HTML tags
    return preg_replace(
        '/<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|"[^"]*"|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>/gixsm',
        !is_string($replaceTo) ? '' : $replaceTo,
        $string
    );
}
```

My regex: `/<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|"[^"]*"|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>/gixsm`

I tested it with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and http://regexpal.com/, it worked well.
But when I tried to run it. Server always returned the error:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\'
```

I have no idea what excactly '\' goes wrong. Someone please help me out!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove only html tags in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412758/how-to-remove-only-html-tags-in-a-string)

Comment: I'm sorry but I want to remove HTML tags which contains nothing. It's not what `strip_tags` does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In php regular expressions you need to escape your delimiters if they occur literally within your expression.

In your case, you have two unescaped `/`; simply replace them with `\/`. You also don't need the array of modifiers -- php is global by default, and you have no literal word characters defined.

Before:

```
/<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|"[^"]*"|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*/?>\s*</\1\s*>/gixsm
```

After:

```
/<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|"[^"]*"|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*\/?>\s*<\/\1\s*>/
//                                                                    ^       ^
```

Comment: Also, remove the `g` modifier. PCRE is global by default.

Comment: You can remove all modifiers.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte indeed, since there are no literal letters defined.

Comment: Thank you all! This's my bad. I'm new to RegEx and it's quite hard to approach.

Comment: @MạnhHaiLúa just happy to see some effort having gone in to the question ;)

Comment: I need to exclude only tag type <a>

Answer (score 4):

This pattern is able to remove "empty tags" (i.e. non self-closing tags where that contain nothing, white-spaces, html comments or other "empty tags"), even if these tags are nested like `<span><span></span></span>`. Tags inside html comments are not taken in account:

```
$pattern = <<<'EOD'
~
<
(?:
    !--[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*-->[^<]*(*SKIP)(*F) # skip comments
  |
    ( # group 1
        (\w++)     # tag name in group 2
        [^"'>]* #'"# all that is not a quote or a closing angle bracket
        (?: # quoted attributes
            "[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*+" [^"'>]* #'"# double quote
          |
            '[^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*+' [^"'>]* #'"# single quote
        )*+
        >
        \s*
        (?:
            <!--[^-]*(?:-(?!->)[^-]*)*+--> \s* # html comments
          |
            <(?1) \s*                          # recursion with the group 1
        )*+
        </\2> # closing tag
    ) # end of the group 1
)
~sxi
EOD;

$html = preg_replace($pattern, '', $html);
```

Limitations:

- This approach will remove links to external Javascript files:
  `<script src="myscript.js"></script>`
- The pattern may remove part of embedded Javascript code if something like:
  `var myvar="<span></span>";`
  or like:
  `var myvar1="<span><!--";
  function doSomething() { alert("!!!"); }
  var myvar2="--></span>";`
  is found.

These limitations are due to the fact that a basic text approach is not able to make the difference between html and javascript code. However, it is possible to solve this problem if you add "script" tags in the pattern skip list (in the same way than html comments), but in this case you need to basically describe the Javascript content (strings, comments, literal patterns, all that is not the previous three) that isn't a trivial task but possible.

Comment: It's absolutely better than mine! Very great and helpful! Thank you!

Comment: Any way to make it work on PHP 5.3 (PCRE 8.12 2011-01-15)? It doesn't seem to match anything whereas things work fine on regex testing sites (phpliveregex or regex101)

Comment: @MarkL: there is no reason the pattern doesn't work with php 5.3 and its corresponding PCRE version, you have probably missed something, I suggest to add `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the beginning of your code to see what happens. Whatever I will improve this answer soon.

Comment: Can't get it to work. 3 different servers, various versions of PHP/PCRE. Error display is enabled. Produces an array with empty values. phpliveregex.com works though. Pulling hair here. Sample code: http://pastie.org/10310797 If I use your code verbatim (with EOD, etc.), it works. What gives?

Comment: @MarkL: your problem is related to how to figure a literal backslash in a string depending of the quotes. see https://eval.in/405609 and the php manual about strings and octal numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Remove empty elements... and the next empty elements.

P.e.

```
<p>Hello!
   <div class="foo"><p id="nobody">
   </p>
      </div>
 </p>
```

Results:

```
<p>Hello!</p>
```

Php code:

```
/* $html store the html content */
do {
    $tmp = $html;
    $html = preg_replace( '#<([^ >]+)[^>]*>([[:space:]]|&nbsp;)*</\1>#', '', $html );
} while ( $html !== $tmp );
```

Comment: Pretty nice indeed! And for the ultimate killer space evolution try this also: `'#<([^ >]+)[^>]*>([[:space:]]|&nbsp;)*</\1>#'`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if that is what u need, but I found this today. You need PHP 5.4+!

```
$oDOMHTML = DOMDocument::loadHTML( 
    $sYourHTMLString, 
    LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | 
    LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | 
    LIBXML_NOBLANKS | 
    LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG 
);
$sYourHTMLStringWithoutEmptyTags = $oDOMHTML->saveXML();
```

Maybe this works for you.

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work. My PHP is 5.4.19. I'll try it a later time (when I understand). Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you give me some example code, this was just written without any tests. Just read the LIBXML_* constants this afternoon.

Comment: Hm, obviously these options just turn "<br></br>" into "<br/>". So it does with "<span></span>" -> "<span/>". Sorry, thought this could probably help. Was worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use recursion to solve for this.  Continue to pass the HTML blob back into the function until the empty tags are no longer present.

```
public static function removeHTMLTagsWithNoContent($htmlBlob) {
    $pattern = "/<[^\/>][^>]*><\/[^>]+>/";

    if (preg_match($pattern, $htmlBlob) == 1) {
        $htmlBlob = preg_replace($pattern, '', $htmlBlob);
        return self::removeHTMLTagsWithNoContent($htmlBlob);
    } else {
        return $htmlBlob;
    }
}
```

This will check for the presence of empty HTML tags and replace them until the regex pattern doesn't match anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of removing all empty tags. (It also removes surronding tags, if they are condisered empty because of empty childrens:

```
/**
 * Remove empty tags.
 * This one will also remove <p><a href="/foo/bar.baz"><span></span></a></p> (empty paragraph with empty link)
 * But it will not alter <p><a href="/foo/bar.baz"><span>[CONTENT HERE]</span></a></p> (since the span has content)
 *
 * Be aware: <img ../> will be treated as an empty tag!
 */
do
{
    $len1 = mb_strlen($string);
    $string = preg_replace('/<(\w+)\b(?:\s+[\w\-.:]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|"[^"]*"|[\w\-.:]+))?)*\s*\/?>\s*<\/\1\s*>/', '', $string);
    $len2 = mb_strlen($string);

} while ($len1 > 0 && $len2 > 0 && $len1 != $len2);
```

I have been using this to sanitize html from an external CMS with positive results.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<p>Some <b>HTML</b> <strong>text. </strong> <hr></p>';
$clean_string = preg_replace('#<[^>]+>#', '', $string);
echo $clean_string; // Some HTML text.
```

Comment: Your answer contains code without explanation. It's better to include details about *how* your answer answers the question.