# How can I remove HTML tag in Python from HTML file?

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, python-3.4

**Summary:** What regex string would I use to remove  tags in a HTML document?
Although, this may be a duplicate from a previous answer: [How to remove only html tags in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412758/how-to-remove-only-html-tags-in-a-string) and [Remove HTML tags in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878452/remove-html-tags-in-string), I can not programme in those languages fully yet, so this is why I am asking the question.

I am completing a Python Exercise by Google: https://developers.google.com/edu/python/exercises/baby-names
it requires you two parse HTML data using regex (the HTML is structured so it is easier). I've been having problems removing the tags surrounding the data:

```
   def extract_names(filename):
  """
  Given a file name for baby.html, returns a list starting with the year string
  followed by the name-rank strings in alphabetical order.
  ['2006', 'Aaliyah 91', Aaron 57', 'Abagail 895', ' ...]
  """
  # +++your code here+++
  #open and read file
  file = open(filename,'r')
  HTML = file.read()
  #html file
  #print(HTML)

  #extract date
  date = re.search(r'(Popularity in )([\d]+)',HTML)
  print('Date: ',date.group(2))

  #find rank and name remove html tags
  ranking_tags = re.findall(r'<td>[\d]</td>',HTML)
  rankings = []
  name_tags = re.findall(r'<td>[a-z]</td>',HTML,re.IGNORECASE)
  names = []

  for value in ranking_tags:
      rankings.append(re.sub('[<td></td>]','',value))

  for value in name_tags:
    names.append(re.sub('[<td></td>]','',value))
  print(rankings)
  print(names)
```

Currently, my regex does not replace the tags, as they're wrong. I have already tried teaching myself how to remove the tags to no avail:
http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/courses/27610/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2.pdf
and
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm
as well as looking at other sights before writing this.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If `regex` is not required and to get the job done you can check existing implementations.

### Django's `strip_tags`:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/html.py#L183

```
def _strip_once(value):
    """
    Internal tag stripping utility used by strip_tags.
    """
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(value)
    s.close()
    return s.get_data()


@keep_lazy_text
def strip_tags(value):
    """Return the given HTML with all tags stripped."""
    # Note: in typical case this loop executes _strip_once once. Loop condition
    # is redundant, but helps to reduce number of executions of _strip_once.
    value = str(value)
    while '<' in value and '>' in value:
        new_value = _strip_once(value)
        if len(new_value) >= len(value):
            # _strip_once was not able to detect more tags
            break
        value = new_value
    return value
```

You can modify that implementation.

### Python Standard Library and its `xml` module

https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

It contains examples on how to use it properly.

### Use `lxml` package

https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_tags

Example usage:

```
strip_tags(some_element,
    'simpletagname',             # non-namespaced tag
    '{http://some/ns}tagname',   # namespaced tag
    '{http://some/other/ns}*'    # any tag from a namespace
    Comment                      # comments (including their text!)
    )
```

Comment: I could use this. But the point of the exercise was to try and use regexes.